# Link/Tag/Track Questions/Answers

Tags: feature-request, tags, linked-questions, tracking

Is there a way of tagging, bundling or linking questions on stack exchange communities? I would like to track my (and/or others) questions on a matter all together so I could use them later as a guide.

I'm thinking of a personal type of tags but not functioning exactly like tags. They should be able to be linked to specific questions.

For example :

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718344/redmine-1-2-1-to-bitnami-redmine-2-5-stack-upgrade-considerations

and

[How can the SVN URL in Redmine be changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22789507/how-can-the-svn-url-in-redmine-be-changed/22813456?noredirect=1#22813456)

These are my questions concerning our Redmine upgrade and me figuring out many different aspects of this process.

I would like to bundle these questions into a personal tag called "Redmine Upgrade" for future reference. It would be much better if the questions in the bundle could be ordered to achieve a workflow like list for the process.

An extra feature could be the ability to share such bundles with public.

Comment: You can click a star under the voting arrows, which will add teh question to the **favorites** tab in your profile. The same way you can remove it from the list.

Comment: This doesn't provide exactly my expectation. In the future I'm going to have multiple favorites which I would like to group. "Favorites" tab is just one massive bundle or grouping tool with every favorited item in it. It wouldn't serve me any good.

Comment: I'm using text file for that, and searching functions quite well and quite fast :) But it would be nice to be able to organize some 'working list' :)

Comment: I think this should be (a request for) an extension of existing "favourite" functionality, as it's a natural extension - both involve marking a question to store a link to it for later, and having both "favourite" functionality and this seems redundant.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the bookmark functionality your browser already provides? Or, perhaps, any of the number of bookmark sharing/syncing services?